# Cast sqlite3_column_value into other datatype in Objective C

Tags: ios, sqlite, object, casting

I need to store the result returned from a Sqlite database into NSMutableArray without specifying the type of data.

```
sqlite3_value *sqlvalue = (sqlite3_column_value(sqlStat, 0));
```

Sorry for my bad english, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really wanted to do this, you might create a `NSData` for your array (e.g. using `NSKeyedArchiver`), and then write this to your database using `sqlite_bind_blob` and retrieve it using `sqlite_column_blob`. Clearly, if you have any custom objects in that array, you have to implement the appropriate `NSCoder` methods.

Personally, I would rather have my data model mirror the structure of my array, not just cryptically store my array as a blob. But both techniques work.

---

To save the array to the database, you could do the following:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];

NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
NSAssert(data, @"archivedDataWithRootObject failed");

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "insert into test (test_array) values (?)", -1, &statement, NULL);
NSAssert(rc == SQLITE_OK, @"prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

rc = sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [data bytes], [data length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
NSAssert(rc == SQLITE_OK, @"bind failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

rc = sqlite3_step(statement);
NSAssert(rc == SQLITE_DONE, @"step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

And to retrieve the array:

```
rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, "select test_id, test_array from test", -1, &statement, NULL);
NSAssert(rc == SQLITE_OK, @"prepare failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

rc = sqlite3_step(statement);
NSAssert(rc == SQLITE_ROW, @"step failure: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

const void * bytes = sqlite3_column_blob(statement, 1);
NSAssert(bytes, @"unable to retrieve bytes from database: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(statement, 1);

NSData *resultData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:length];

NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:resultData];
NSAssert(newArray, @"Unable to unarchiveObjectWithData");

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Comment: For example in java I can get any data from SQlite and store in an Object type variable and then cast to the type of data that I want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
const char *value = (const char *)sqlite3_column_value(sqlStat, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, i tried that but i get rare characters. Is it possible to cast into id for store in NSMuttableArray ?

Comment: You can cast that char[] to a NSString, and store it

Comment: And how about cast it to id for store in nsmuttablearray please ?

Comment: You can close this question and ask it in a different one

Comment: if you want to store the value as a pointer in an NSMutableArray *myArray; Then try this
`code`

const char *value =  (const char *)sqlite3_column_value(sqlStat, 0);

[myArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:value]];

`code`